# Show big code in one device and hide same code in another devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show a button with `btn-lg` size in extra small devices. and show same button with `btn-xs` size in another devices.

So is there better suggestion of below code?

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back</a>
</div>

<div class="visible-xs-block">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back</a>
</div>
```

Given that I may have a piece of code is much bigger than a button code. Like this:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
<!-- A LONG AND COMPLEX CODE IN HERE -->
</div>

<div class="visible-xs-block">
<!-- SAME LONG AND COMPLEX CODE IN HERE (with just change some classes of size) -->
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because your are using bootstrap grid system and trying to do opposite thing ( i.e:- showing large button on small screens ) so I will advise you create you own button and then add media queries to have the right size applied

Comment: @DhavalChheda: `btn-xs`or `btn-lg` only define the size of a button, not it's visibility like in `hidden-*` or `visible-*`. So it does actually work.
 @NabiKAZ: Why not put the `visible-xs` class on only those elements in the exact same long code, that you want to have changed. If there are too much occurrences, then you would need to define your own CSS with media-queries.